# Confused about Null Safety in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I am new to Kotlin and have read more than one time about [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) in Kotlin but I am really confused and do not understand clearly. Can anyone helps me answer questions below:

1. What does `!` character in `fun getString(key: String!)` mean?
2. Are names of operators below correct:

`?.`: Safe call operator

`?:`: Elvis operator

`!!`: Sure operator

3. What does differences between `?:` operator and `?.let`? When should I use each one?

Comment: To answer your 1st question have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826699/single-exclamation-mark-in-kotlin)

Comment: The safe call means do this or if the object is `null` return `null`. The elvis operator means if the expression is `null` then return the thing after it (e.g. `null ?: 1` will return `1`).

Comment: Thanks, I understood those operators but want to sure about its name.

Comment: The names are correct except for `!!` as this one doesn't really have a name.

Comment: !! = Hold My Beer operator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one that is the single `exclamation mark (!)` is called the **platform type**. What it does is that, Kotlin doesn't know how that value will turn out. Whether null or not null so it leaves it to you to decide.

The second one (`?.`) is a **safe-call operator**. It allows you to combine a method call and a null check into a single operation.

```
val x:String?
x="foo"
println(x?.toUpperCase())
```

The third one (`?:`) is an **Elvis Operator** or the ***Null-Coalescing operator*** . It provides a default pre-defined value instead of null when used.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x:String?;
    x=null;
    println(x?:"book".toUpperCase())
}
```

In this instance, the printed value will be `"BOOK"` since `x` is `null`.

The last one doesn't really have a name. It is usually referred to as *Double-bang* or *Double exclamation mark*. What it does is that it throws a `null pointer exception` when the value is `null`.

```
val x:String?;
x=null;
println(x!!.toUpperCase())
```

This will throw a null pointer exception.

`?.let` ---> the **let function**

The let function turns an object on which it is called into a parameter of a function usually expressed using a lambda expression. When used with a safe call operator (`?.`), the let function conveniently converts a nullable object to an object of a non-nullable type.

Let's say we have this function.

```
fun ConvertToUpper (word: String) {word.toUpperCase()}
```

The parameter of ConvertToUpper isn't null so we can't pass a null argument to it.

```
val newWord: String? = "foo"
ConvertToUpper(newWord)
```

The above code wouldn't compile because `newWord` can be null and our `ConvertToUpper` function doesn't accept a  `null` argument.

We can explicitly solve that using an if expression.

```
if(newWord != null) ConvertToUpper(newWord)
```

The let function simplifies this for us by calling the function only is the value passed to it isn't null.

```
newWord?.let {ConvertToUpper(it)}
```