# What is the significance of a ! following a type in kotlin?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Code:

```
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel
val sock = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open()
```

Intellij identifies the type of 'sock' as `AsynchronousSocketChannel!` (with the !).
However if I manually specify the type as `:AsynchronousSocketChannel` the code also works (and Intellij no longer indicates the '!'), so the ! is only some annotation on the type.  But what does this annotation signify?  It would be great to know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826699/single-exclamation-mark-in-kotlin

Comment: Guys are right - it is a duplicate. But ! indicates so called platform type.

Comment: thanks...yes, could not find that one by search but it gives the answer