# What is meaning of ! operator in Kotlin RxJava Flowable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

What is the difference between `Flowable<List<VanDataModel>>` and `Flowable<List<VanDataModel!>!>` in Kotlin using Rx ?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Answer (score 4):

It's Kotlin, not RxJava. A type notated with `!` is called [**platform type**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) coming from Java APIs. You could refer to platform types as *"types of unknown nullability"*. Also important to know is that you cannot use the exclamation-marked type for your own types, it's not part of the Kotlin syntax, it's only a notation

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713582/8073652).