# What is the meaning of Type! in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, type-systems

I'm very aware of the Kotlin null safeness. I Know "?" after a type (ex: Int?) can be used to declare a variable or value as nullable. I also know that !! operator is used to return a non-null value or throw NPE.

In general, a type with "?" after it will be nullable, and without "?" is a non-null. But I have seen when I'm inspecting some variables something like this:

> var myVariable: Int!

It happens when you use java code from kotlin code.

```
//java code
public class Foo {
    public Integer calcNumber()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I use the function Foo.calcNumber()

```
//kotlin code
val meh = Foo().calcNumber()
print(meh)
```

the value meh is inspected as Int!, not Int nor Int?. Obviously here the value meh can be null, but it is not correctly "detected" by the "IDE".

As

```
var a: Int! = 10
```

is invalid, my question is: What does exactly mean types with "!"?

Comment: "Platform Types" - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types ; the linked question should given more information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Type!` notation is called a [Platform Type and is critical for Interoperability with the weaker-typed Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types); it means "the null-ability is unknown" and it allows for relaxed null-ability enforcement. I found the examples in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826699/single-exclamation-mark-in-kotlin) underwhelming.. although all the information is there.

The following program is *accepted as type-safe*, as Kotlin allows the type of the x/Int! expression to be used as "Int or Int?".

```
var x = JavaIntegerList.get(0); // Int! type inferred by Kotlin
var y: Int? = x;
var z: Int = x;
```

However, the assignment to z (Int) will fail at run-time *if* x evaluates to null. (For class implementation types, the NPE may delayed to usage: basically, Kotlin chooses to 'get out of the way'.)

It's thus designed for cases when it is known that the value "cannot" be null in a valid program, although the value comes from Java outside of the Kotlin type system. Highly applicable to `int`-box-`Integer` in Java, although it is valid for *any* class type / value coming in from Java. If the Java code *can* return `null`, it is safest to put the value into a `Type?` immediately and then correctly deal with the null-ability.

Compare this to the Java code with similar run-time failure semantics:

```
// Java
Integer x = JavaIntegerList.get(0);
Integer y = x;  // "No OP" - all class types in Java are null-able
int z = (int)x; // kaboom *at run-time* if x is null!
```

While simple to show with ints, as in this example, this issue is not strictly related to Java's `int/Integer` types. The document linked above shows a case of `String!` being implicitly used, giving the example that `item.substring(1)`, where item is a `String!` is allowed/type-safe but will fail at run-time if `item` evaluates to null.