# Java: anObject?.property What does it mean?

Tags: java

I saw this in java code.
`"anObject?.property"` and 
`"anObject?.getProperty()"`.

I have tried look for it online. But could not find any.
What does "?." mean here in Java?

Comment: This doesn't exist in Java. Are you sure it wasn't something else, like Kotlin or Scala?

Comment: *If* it was actually Kotlin, then this has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826699/single-exclamation-mark-in-kotlin

Comment: This isn't core Java, but it would be present in Groovy, Kotlin, or EL, among others.

Comment: You guys are right. It is in groovy file. Since most groovy code are kinda in/similar to Java. So I was confused.

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer or comment to ask for more ?

Answer (score 0):

This does not exists is `Java`

---

You may find this in `Kotlin` and this is called [*null safety*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

```
val a = "Kotlin"
val b: String? = null
println(b?.length)
println(a?.length)
```