# Kotlin Data Type With Exclamation Point

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin in Android, and I'm seeing some things return a type with a `!`, for example, [WifiInfo.getSSID()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getSSID()) returns a string that is of type `String!`. What does the ! do?

Bonus question, why can't I find this in the Kotlin documentation?

Comment: Platform types: [Single exclamation mark in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43826699)

Comment: Documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` says "this can be `null`".

`!` says "we do not know if this can be `null` or not, but we will assume that it cannot".

In Android and other Kotlin/JVM environments, you get `!` from "platform types" — basically, types returned from libraries (e.g., the Android SDK) where the return value was not annotated with `@Nullable` or `@NotNull`.