# What does the single exclamation "!" mean after the type in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android

I'm learning to Develop Android Apps using `Kotlin`. I previously used to Develop using `Java`. While coding in Android Studio, I can see that the return types, parameters, etc. used in the Lambdas, methods, etc. are written as View!.

I know that the `?` after the type in Kotlin means a Nullable type. Though what does the `!` mean.

For example:

```
val item = mySpinner.selectedItem
```

The return type is `Any!` What does the ! mean? Is it the same as a Nullable type i.e. `Any?` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types)  indicating that `Kotlin` is not sure whether it will  be `null` or `not  null`, it's like saying "maybe".

> platform types can't be mentioned explicitly in the program, so there's no syntax for them in the language. Nevertheless, the compiler and IDE need to display them sometimes (for example, in error messages or parameter info), so there is a mnemonic notation for them:
>
> - T! means "T or T?",
> - (Mutable)Collection! means "Java collection of    T may be mutable or not, may be nullable or not",
> - Array<(out) T>!    means "Java array of T (or a subtype of T), nullable or not"

And because it can either be `null` or `not null`, it is up to you how you will treat it.

Also check this another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826699/single-exclamation-mark-in-kotlin)